# IIS custom error page when site is switched off

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to proceed custom error page, when all websites(not server itself!) on IIS been turned off? In our work process we need to turn off site, but users could still look at it and get ugly 404 browser screen? 
Windows Server 10
IIS 7
Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?